# scrapy not working with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am writing a scrapy spider with selenium to cral a dynamic web page.
I am pretty sure the regular expression works fine.But the 'page_link' from the linkextractor is getting nothing and the program terminates before  parse_item function get called. Can't figure out what is wrong.

```
    class OikotieSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = 'oikotie'
        allowed_domains = [my_domain]

        start_urls=['https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/myytavat-uudisasunnot?cardType=100&locations=%5B%22helsinki%22%5D&newDevelopment=1&buildingType%5B%5D=1&buildingType%5B%5D=256&pagination=1']

        def __init__(self):
            CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
            chrome_driver = 'mydriver_location'
            os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chrome_driver
            chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
            chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

            #driver instance and call
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
            self.driver.get('my_url')
            self.selector=Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
            self.driver.close()
            self.driver.quit()




        page_link=LinkExtractor(allow=('myytavat-asunnot\/helsinki\/\d+',))


        rules = (
            # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
            Rule(page_link, callback='parse_item',follow=True),
        )


        def parse_item(self, response):
            self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
            print("parse_item is called!!")
            self.driver.get(response.url)
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
            return ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use 'DownloadMiddleware' to achieve getting webpage. In 'DownloadMiddlewrae', you can init browser to get webpage. Look at this:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=DownloadMiddleware

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your LinkExtractor `allow` argument is not an absolute regex.  It needs to be:https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html.

Now part of being an absolute regex could just be *+current regex....but that would be terrible:).  Just make it absolute.